# Unable to load template in theme app in production environment

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I have a problem with our theme plugin (app based). We have extended the product with several custom fields (rte). When they are filled, they will displayed as separate tabs on the detail page.

**File/Folder Structure**

- views/abettercms/page/product-detail/tab-one.html.twig
- views/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig

**Extended block in views/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig**

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig' %}
...
{% block page_product_detail_tabs_content_description %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {% if page.product.customFields and page.product.customFields.areanet_standardtheme_products_tab_1 %}
        <div class="tab-pane fade show"
                id="tab-one-pane"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="tab-one">
            {% sw_include '@AreanetStandardtheme64/abettercms/page/product-detail/tab-one.html.twig' %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

In dev-mode it's working like expected and the additional tab is showing. But in prod-mode a exception is throwing:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\LoaderError: 
"Unable to load template "abettercms/page/product-detail/tab-one.html.twig". 
(Looked into: AreanetStandardtheme64, SwagPayPal, Framework, Administration,  Storefront) 
in "@AreanetStandardtheme64/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig" at line xyz"
```

Tested in 6.4.0.18 (detail page is not displayed => error) and 6.4.0.20 (detail page is displayed without additional tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the custom template folder from "views/abettercms/..." to "views/storefront/abettercms/..." - then the templates will be synced to the database.

```
{% sw_include '@AreanetStandardtheme64/storefront/abettercms/page/product-detail/tab-one.html.twig' %}
```

Templates outside "views/storefront" are not working in prod mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you reinstall your app in prod mode after you made changes to the templates. in prod mode the template content is loaded from the database and the templates are synced into the database on app install or app update.

To verify you can check the `app_template` table and check that all the template changes you made are there in the database and have the same content as the original template files. If not a reinstall of the app should update the DB.

Answer (score 0):

> Please ensure that you reinstall your app in prod mode after you made changes to the templates. in prod mode the template content is loaded from the database and the templates are synced into the database on app install or app update.

We have reinstalled the app in prod mode, but the app_template table was not updated.

We have added the entries manually to the database, than it's working in prod-mode.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFFjT.png)

But the entries/changes in "views/abettercms" are not automatically created during app update or reinstallation. All other changes in "views/storefront" are synced correctly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I also have tested it on clean 6.4.20 installation. Set .env to production, upload theme-app as zip, install, activate it and choose the theme on the sales channel.

The database entries for the the templates in "views/abettercms" are not generated.